# prweb deployment -tomcat-issue

Tags: tomcat

Need your help to check the attached log file and let me know the issue related to the start and deployment of the WAR file

```
18-Jul-2022 17:21:54.071 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:54.075 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:54.091 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:54.100 INFO [Thread-2] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.416 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.22
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 2 2022 16:53:56 UTC
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.22.0
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            12.4
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           18.0.1.1+0
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Homebrew
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.420 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.420 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.427 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.427 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.427 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/conf/logging.properties
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.428 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/temp
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.436 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/deeps/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.626 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [349] milliseconds
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.671 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.22]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.680 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/prweb.war]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:55.999 INFO [main] java.util.ArrayList.forEach Name = PRFileStore Ignoring unknown property: value of "Database-based File Access" for "description" property
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.013 INFO [main] java.util.ArrayList.forEach Name = AdminPegaRULES Ignoring unknown property: value of "PegaRULES Admin datasource" for "description" property
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.041 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.042 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.052 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/prweb] startup failed due to previous errors
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.061 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/prweb.war] has finished in [381] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.066 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/prhelp.war]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.224 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/prhelp.war] has finished in [169] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.236 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/docs]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.303 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/docs] has finished in [68] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/manager]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.387 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/manager] has finished in [87] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.391 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/examples]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.556 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/examples] has finished in [176] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/ROOT]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.634 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [68] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/host-manager]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.705 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/10.0.22/libexec/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [71] ms
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.708 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-Jul-2022 17:21:56.717 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [1070] milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Pega platform is not supported in Tomcat version 10. Install tomcat 9 and check

https://docs-previous.pega.com/platform-support-guide?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33498609)